# reaction mechanisms of peroxides

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

Task: Explain the reaction mechanism of 1,4-Dioxane in terms of how you get peroxides. Start here with the autoxidation with one radical X.

My explanation:

in the first step 1,4 Dioxan reacts with Dioxygen, so one gets an initiatorradical and and HOO* (* symbolises here a free electron, a radical). In the second step the initiatorradical reacts with oxygen and one receives a peroxyradical. In the end the peroxyradical reacts with an hydrogen atom and one comes to hydroperoxide. Is that right?[image]

Comment: You can't have free hydrogen atoms floating around in solution. The requisite hydrogen atom comes from dioxane itself.

Comment: Doesn't the dioxane get the hydrogen atom from another substance? And is the rest correct?

Comment: Right, i got it. It comes from the 1,4-Dioxane. Thanks! But what would be the Initation here? the first step, which I draw? and the second line would be the propagation? Is there an termination step, too?

Answer (score 2):

I could not find a definitive mechanism for 1,4-dioxane, but this is the mechanism for the formation of THF peroxide is likely very similar

[image]

[diagram from here](https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/2015/OB/C5OB00012B#!divAbstract)

Comment: So, the initiation is always that R* (here an hydrogen-atom) will be separated? Could the molecule do not react with oxygen at first, so that you get an peroxyradical and in the end this radical reacts with a hydrogen-atom to hydroperoxide?

Comment: I've edited the question, Would it look like this?

Comment: & is it right that 1,4-dioxane prefers to do autoxidation because it is an ether (it contains oxygen-atoms in it, connected to two different alkyl rests.). Or are there any other reasons, why it does like to do autoxidation?

Comment: The radical is stablised by the oxygen. This is why all ether-based solvents have a warning for peroxide formation.

Comment: But why do cyclic ethers tend more to peroxides than acyclic ethers?

Comment: Do they? AFAIK all ethers are prone to peroxide formation, this article may be worth your time, page 5 containing the most useful information http://ccc.chem.pitt.edu/wipf/Web/16340.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Liquid-Phase Photolysis of Dioxane has been studied in several occasions in the past. One of these studies, several neat aliphatic ethers including dioxane were irradiated for $\ce{24 h}$ with a medium-pressure mercury lamp (Ref.1). As a result, the neat liquid-phase dioxane has been reported to yield gaseous, liquid, and solid products after the irradiation. Among the products, the major gaseous products were identified as $\ce{H2, CO, CH4, C2H4,}$ and $\ce{C2H6}$, but the liquid products have not been analyzed. However, the solid products were shown to be the racemic and *meso* forms of dioxyldioxane (see total reaction illustrated in the diagram to give solid product):

[image: Dioxyldioxane formation]

Pfordte rationalized the formation of dioxyldioxane as a simple dimerization of dioxyl radical formed by photoinitiated hydrogen abstraction from dioxane (Ref.1, 2):

[image: Dimerization]

Thus, it is safe to conclude that dioxane is susceptible to sun light and/or a foreign radical from any other source. Thus, after a long time exposure to sunlight or a in the presence of a foreign radical, the formation of dioxyl radicals is possible and exposure to environment would supply oxygen (also dissolved $\ce{O2}$) to further react as shown in the propagation step as follows:

[image: Autooxygenation]

**References:**

1. Von Klaus Pfordte, “Intermolekulare Dehydrierungen durch UV-Licht, IV – Photoreaktionen der Äther,” *Justus Liebigs Ann. Chem.* **1959**, *625(1)*, 30–33 (in German) (https://doi.org/10.1002/jlac.19596250104).
2. P. H. Mazzocchi, M. W. Bowen, “Photolysis of dioxane,” *J. Org. Chem.* **1975**, *40(18)*, 2689–2690 (DOI: 10.1021/jo00906a029).